# Init.d Script won't work to keep value

Tags: android-emulator, init.d

I was try to change some value like vm, lowmemorykiller, adj, and net using shell script, then save it to init.d folder and execute it as root.

after reboot, it always back to default.

And i was trying to do this :

adding this command :

`busybox sysctl -w or sysctl -e -w`

`busybox chmod 755 or 777 /path`

`mount -o remount, rw/system`

and doing this :

set permission to 755/777

give a number in name like 99userinit

i have busybox installed and init.d support too

but it still can't changes, so what shoud i do ???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the classic Android Emulator (so not the newer, *ranchu* version), any changes you make on the `/system` partition will be discarded on reboot by default.

To work around this, you should:

1. Perform any needed operations.
2. Backup the temporary system image.

   On Linux, this is located under `/tmp/android-[YOUR_USERNAME]/` and is a file called `emulator-[SOMETHING]`.

   On Windows it should be under `C:\Users\[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\[RANDOM_FILE_NAME.tmp]` (although I have not checked the latter).

   Copy this file to a handy location, as it is removed when the emulator is killed.
3. Restart the emulator with the new system image (backup the original image, rename the new one to `system.img` and place it in the avd directory, then start the emulator).

[Source](http://blog.vishalon.net/tutorial-how-to-make-a-change-permanent-in-system-folder-for-android-emulator-yaffs2ext4)